# SQL zeros and NULL

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and am reading through this book:
Murach SQL Server 2008 for Developers.
On page 441 there is some example code dealing with a RAISERROR statement.
I understand most of that no problem, but I do not understand what these
two *zeros* and *NULL* are?
I understand that it is dealing with an INSERT statement with values for a table.
I included a link to a screenshot of the code with red lines pointing out the *zeros* and  *NULL*.
https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/837/testforforeignkey.jpg

Comment: they are just values that will be inserted on a specific column `:)`

Comment: what is the invoices table look like?

Comment: the Invoices table looks like https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/405/invoicetable.jpg and https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/267/invoicestable2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The VALUES clause represents the values for each column in a row of the target table.  Therefore, you'd cross-reference the VALUES list with the schema of the Invoices table.

@VendorId would most likely go in the VendorID column.
0, 0, and NULL represent values for 3 of the other columns.

Also, it is bad practice to use the short-form of the INSERT statement.  When you say "INSERT Invoices" and don't specify the column names, it causes unnecessary work for someone to look up the schema of the table.

It is better to say

```
INSERT Invoices (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES ('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')
```

as it is much more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

the zero are for PaymentTotal and CreditTotal
and the null is for PaymentDate

since the example do not explicitly tell the column in the insert, you have to go in the order it is display

this is a bad practice